# How to change the weights of a adjacency matrix according to a data frame values?

Tags: r, dataframe, adjacency-matrix

I have a weighted adjacency matrix like below:

```
adj<-read.table(text="    a_fgh   c_dfg   l_opu
a_fgh   0   3.3 5.6
                c_dfg   3.3 0   8.5
                l_opu   5.6 8.5 0",
                header=TRUE)
adjMat<-as.matrix(adj)
```

I also have a table which is as follows:

```
    table<-read.table(text="name1   name2    (3,4.5)     (4.5,6)     (6,7.5)     (7.5,9)
fgh_a   opu_l   10  -31 75  -69
fgh_a   dfg_c   45  60  30  33  38
dfg_c   opu_p   75  57  40  22  -63
opu_l   dfg_c   -69 -56 78  96  78
",
                    header=TRUE)
```

I want to change the weights of my adjacency matrix according to the top table. For example a_fgh has interaction with l_opu and the weight of that is 5.6.

However according to the table value of the weight of edge between `a_fgh` and `l_opu` if is among 4.5 to 6 must be -6. By these the adjacency matrix would be as below:

```
adj2<-read.table(text="     a_fgh   c_dfg   l_opu
    a_fgh   0   60  -6
                  c_dfg 60  0   8.5
                  l_opu -6  78  0",
                header=TRUE)
adjMat2<-as.matrix(adj)
```

Comment: can you do `dput(data)` we need to know how exactly thedata looks like from your end

Comment: @Onyambu I tried to give a reproducible example. My data has this structure, however it much larger than this.

Comment: The `table` what are its column names??

Comment: @Onyambu the first row contatins the column names.

Comment: How can you have (1.5,3)as column name.. okay.. will look at it and let you know

Comment: I know, this another problem I have with that. I appreciate it.